# Issue regarding javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a link tag `(anchor tag)` dynamically using **javascript**. 
There is a javascript function which will be fired by an event and it will create a javascript link.

I have already mentioned the required attributes for the newly created anchor tag using javascript. Now I have also mentioned an `onclick` event on that anchor tag.

**The problem is**

that the `onclick` event is fired during the anchor tag creation. And it is firing for that one time. Next time when I am clicking on the link, I am unable to get my desired result.

**javascript code:**

```
function waybill()
{
    var mail_link = document.createElement("a");
    mail_link.href = "javascript:void(0)";
    mail_link.className = 'animated bounceInDown';
    mail_link.innerHTML = "Mail Waybill";
    mail_link.onclick = abc_test();
    var holder_div = document.getElementById("holder");
    holder_div.appendChild(mail_link);
}
function abc_test()
{
    alert("mail link clicked");
}
```

I am getting the alert only once and without even clicking.
Please help me.

Comment: where is html code ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mail_link.onclick = abc_test()` will invoke `abc_test` and assign its return value to `mail_link.onclick`.

If you just want to reference the function, and not call it, leave out the `()`:

```
mail_link.onclick = abc_test;
```

Adding event listeners is one of those things that a lot of old browsers are doing in their own way, and it's a bit messy to add support for all of them. Sicnce the question is tagged jQuery, you could do all of this in jQuery and have browser support handled for you:

```
$('<a/>', {
   href: 'javascript:void(0);',
   'class': 'animated bounceInDown',
   text: 'Mail Waybill',
}).appendTo('#holder').click(abc_test);
```

Comment: We really need a canonical for this, if there isn't one already.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that calling abc_test() will execute the function while using only abc_test will pass a reference to the function. in this case you need to change the line:

```
mail_link.onclick = abc_test();
```

with the line:

```
mail_link.onclick = abc_test;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because that you've invoked the function instead of referencing it.

---

**mail_link.onclick=abc_test();** - This will invoke the function while initializing 
**mail_link.onclick=abc_test;** - This will add a reference of the function to onClick, so that it will invoke the function while you click the anchor link.